# Fetching Data from XML through PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have a huge amount of data in an XML file, however while fetching the data through my PHP code, the webpage goes into processing and then hangs. There are more than 17,000 records in the XML (the data related to a city name). I have received a few suggestions that I should filter the data by state, but am unable to implement that suggestion.

```
<?php
$q = $_GET["q"];
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('http://aayam.co/wp-content/themes/squirreltheme/ifsc/cd_catalog.xml');

$x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('CITY');

for ($i = 0; $i <= $x->length - 1; $i++) {
    // Process only element nodes
    if ($x->item($i)->nodeType == 1) {
        if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q) {
            $y = ($x->item($i)->parentNode);
        }
    }
}

$cd = ($y->childNodes);

for ($i = 0; $i < $cd->length; $i++) {  
    // Process only element nodes
    if ($cd->item($i)->nodeType == 1) {
        echo "<b style='color:green;'>" . $cd->item($i)->nodeName . ":</b> ";
        echo "<div style='color:green;'>" . $cd->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "        </div>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things to look into:
1. XPath (for querying XML):
   http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp
   http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

2. Increasing max execution time:
   e.g.: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes`

Comment: might be  related to php.ini settings for max processing time limit and max memory

Comment: Yeah, max memory could be an issue too...

Comment: @Banerjee post a snippet of your xml

Comment: @Havelock, sure sir i will keep in mind this